# Check HTTP Status

Tags: 7

Is there a way to see what the HTTP status code is for a given page in Drupal?

For example, if I land on an access denied or page not found, can I see that in a status code and use it?

I am using Contexts to set block layouts, but on a 403/404 page, I don't want to show blocks. The same thing goes for Views- for some reason the pages are not redirecting to my custom error page, so setting ~path is not working.

I know there is a Context Error module that sets context if the page is 403 or 404, but I want to do the opposite, where the context is active IF the page is neither a 403 or 404, so I need to check the headers, not the path.

Edit: Unless there is a part of Context that I am missing to check page/view access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this in context you should be able use context error to create a context; then, create a separate context which only applies if that context is not set.

To check the status code in code you can see what is returned by [drupal_get_headers()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_headers/6)

Comment: drupal_get_headers() was only showing me charset and content type.

Comment: if 'drupal_access_denied()' is called then it should set an error visible in drupal_get_headers. Do  you know how the error is being generated, is it standard permissions?

Comment: It's generated from an Access setting in a View.

Comment: I'm also using Pressflow

Comment: I moved my code from hook_init to hook_footer with better results.